# Rsyncing files without taking into account change in timestamps

Tags: rsync

Consider the following structure:

I develop using SVN.

Once I am done I export the revision `\qa\project`

Once QAing is complete, I `rsync` the files to **staging area**.

I am using the following `rsync` command:

`rsync -rlzv --progress --delete /qa/project/ username@server:/var/www/project/`

My problem is, **every time I export from svn I change the timestamp**.

A solution **I will not use** is to use svn on my qa folder and use `update svn`.

What I need is, a way to **rsync my files ignoring timestamp only changes**.

How can I do that?

**EDIT #1:**

**Possible solutions:**

- Using the `-c` for checksum will create a deeper comparison
- Using the `--size-only` will ignore timestamps (check size only)

Comment: Is this really a problem? `rsync` will notice the files are the same apart from the timestamp and will update only the timestamp leaving the content untransferred and unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check manual page for [`rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)?

I believe that `--size-only` switch should do what you need:

> **--size-only**
>
> This modifies rsync’s "quick check" algorithm for finding files that need to be transferred, changing it from the default of transferring files with either a changed size or a changed last-modified time to  just looking for files that have changed in size.  This is useful when starting to use rsync after using another mirroring system which may not preserve timestamps exactly.

Comment: I looked for them here http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync